# How to check if an object (X) is mapped to another object (Y) and, if it is, check if a certain field of the object (Y) is false

Tags: python, django, django-models

So i have these classes in my `models.py`:

```
class Result(models.Models):
  student = models.OneToOneField(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  passed = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)

class Student(models.Models):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
```

So i need to filter `Student` in such that way that the value that `Student.objects.filter()` returns is: if a `Student` is mapped to a `Result` and that `Result` has `passed = False` then it will return that object, and even if it is not mapped to a `Result`, I still need to obtain that `Student` (since not all students have a `Result`).

Comment: Check if instance of Student is in Result. If not, get the student. If present, check the passed status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use related accessors filtering, and [Q object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)
In your case:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
Student.objects.filter(Q(result__passed=False) | Q(result__isnull=True))
```